# Classe selectpicker Bootstrap, não reconhece inserção de <option> via jquery (.html())

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

Estou utilizando framework Bootstrap, e a classe Selectpicker para receber os dados da cidade conforme estado. O script funciona bem, retorna dados, porém ao invés de inserir `<option> Cidade X </option>` ele insere apenas `Cidade X`. Sei que o problema é na classe, mas não sei como resolver.
Classe:

```
<div class="col-md-3  col-xs-4" id="cidade">

<select data-width="auto" id="municipio" name="municipio" class="selectpicker municipio">
    <option value="0" disabled="disabled">Selecione o estado</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#estado").change(function() {

        var est = document.getElementById("estado").value; 

        debugger;

        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
         url: 'cidade.php',
         data: {
          cd_estado: est
         },
         success: function(dados) {
            $(".municipio").html(dados);
         }
         });

    });
});
```

Comment: opa consegui resolver o meu problema que era igual o téu nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941749/bootstrap-select-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Quando você utiliza o .html () você sobrescreve inclusive o elemento select, imaginando que você esteja trazendo com ajax  as "options" desse select, utilize a função append () para adicionar elementos filhos no select.

Edit: traga o elemento montado de seu controler, ou seja, traga-o dentro das tags "option".

Comment: Estou trazendo os dados montados `<option value="Cod_Cidade"> Cidade X </option>`. Usei sua sugestão, mas com o `append()` também está sobrescrevendo o `select`. Essa classe `selectpicker` traz muitas funcionalidades, mas é complicado conseguir alterar seu conteúdo via javascript. Não estou conseguindo ainda. Obrigada pela dica.

Comment: Bom, eu vi que voce depende de outro combobox, logo pra resolver seu problema traga o select das cidades completo o elemento e as opcoes. Crie uma Div pra receber o componente.

Comment: Não resolveu. deve ser proteção da classe do bootstrap. Só consegui resolver não usando .selectpicker :(